# monaco editor dynamic set viewzone's height

Tags: monaco-editor

I used monaco editor's OverlayWidget and Viewzone api to insert a inline text in monaco editor like the monaco editor example https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-listening-to-mouse-events.

but when I changed the OverlayWidget's height, the Viewzone's height was not changed.

I tried use layoutZone api to reset viewzone's height, but It seemed not work.

```
editor.changeViewZones((accessor => {
       accessor.layoutZone(viewZoneId);
       this.doLayout(host, layoutInfo);
}))
```

So what is the correct way to dynamic set viewzone's height?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem。

yes, accessor.layoutZone(viewZoneId); will reRender the viewzone.

the key is use a getter method of viewzone's heightInPx property like below;

```js
const viewZone = {
      afterLineNumber: lineNumber,
      get heightInPx() {
          return host.offsetHeight;
      },
      domNode,
          onDomNodeTop: (top) => {host.style.top = top + 'px'},
     }
```